# Node.js / AWS Lambda ends before SNS Push has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Maybe somebody who is good at Node.js can solve this problem.**

While writing and testing my code on Amazon Web Service I noticed, that Lambda sometimes ends the function before the SNS has been published. I think the problem might be occuring, because "context.done" gets called to early. But logically this case should not happen. IMPORTANT INFORMATION: The code works correctly! (Apart of the thing I mentioned before).

The basic idea of the code is: As soon as an entry in the DynamoDB changes, Lambda reacts and notifies the "Owner" via SNS Push.

Thanks for your help!

---

This code is running on a Lambda instance.

```
console.log('Loading function');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context){

    var target = null;
    var status = null;

    event.Records.forEach(function(record){

            console.log("Function Invoked");
            console.log("Function Event: "+record.eventName);

            if(record.eventName === "MODIFY")
            {
                db_record_exists(record, function(r) {
                    if (r) {

                        if(r.handle == "true"){
                            creator = r.creator;
                            participant = r.participant;

                            creator = JSON.stringify(creator);
                            status = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.status.S);
                            creator = creator.replace(/"/g, "");
                            status = status.replace(/"/g, "");

                            participant = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S);
                            participant = participant.replace(/"/g, "");

                            console.log("creator: "+ creator);
                            console.log("status: "+ status);
                            console.log("participant is: "+ participant);

                            getCredentialsMovement(creator,participant,function(response){
                                console.log("RESPONSE: "+ response);

                                sendSNSmovement(response, status, context);

                            });

                        }else{
                            context.done();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else if(record.eventName == "INSERT"){
                db_record_exists(record, function(r) {
                    if (r) {

                        if(r.handle == "true"){
                            creator = r.creator;
                            participant = r.participant;

                            creator = JSON.stringify(creator);
                            status = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.status.S);
                            creator = creator.replace(/"/g, "");
                            status = status.replace(/"/g, "");

                            participant = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S);
                            participant = participant.replace(/"/g, "");

                            console.log("creator: "+ creator);
                            console.log("status: "+ status);
                            console.log("participant is: "+ participant);

                            getCredentialsInvitation(creator,participant,function(response){
                                console.log("RESPONSE: "+ response);

                                sendSNSinvitation(response, context);

                            });

                        }else{
                            context.done();
                        }
                    } else context.done();
                });
            }else{
                context.done();
            }
        }
    );
};



function db_record_exists(record, callback){

    var users = {};
    users.creator = record.dynamodb.NewImage.creator.S;
    users.participant = record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S;

    if(users.creator != users.participant){
        users.handle = "true";
    }else{
        users.handle = "false";
    }

    callback(users);
}

function shutdown(context){
    context.done();
}


function sendSNSmovement(creator_information, status, context){

    var sns = new aws.SNS();
    var payload_negative = creator_information.name + " has declined your event!";
    var payload_positive = creator_information.name + " has accepted your event!";
    //var payload_positive = "Positive";

    var payload_accepted = {
        "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Your event has been accepted!!\"} }"
    };

    var payload_declined = { "GCM": "{ \"data\":  { \"message\": \"Your event has been declined!\" } }" };

    //   console.log("Standart Message as JSON: "+ payload_declined.GCM);

    payload_declined.GCM = "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \""+payload_negative+"\" } }";
    payload_accepted.GCM = "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \""+payload_positive+"\" } }";


    //   console.log("Standart Message as JSON: "+ payload_declined.GCM);
    //  console.log("Standart Message as String: "+ JSON.stringify(payload_declined));


    payload_accepted = JSON.stringify(payload_accepted);
    payload_declined = JSON.stringify(payload_declined);

    var payload;

    if(status == "true"){
        payload = payload_accepted;
    }else{
        payload = payload_declined;
    }


    var params = {
        TargetArn: creator_information.arn,
        MessageStructure: 'json',
        Message: payload
    };

    sns.publish(
        params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
// Notify Lambda that we are finished, but with errors

                context.done(err, 'Brians Function Finished with Errors!');

            }else{
                console.log('push sent');
                console.log(data);
// Notify Lambda that we are finished

                context.done();
            }

        });
}

function sendSNSinvitation(creator_information,context){

    var sns = new aws.SNS();
    var payload_message = creator_information.name + " has invited you to an event!";

    var payload = {
        "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Your event has been accepted!!\"} }"
    };


    payload.GCM = "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \""+payload_message+"\" } }";



    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);


    var params = {
        TargetArn: creator_information.arn,
        MessageStructure: 'json',
        Message: payload
    };

    sns.publish(
        params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);

// Notify Lambda that we are finished, but with errors

                context.done(err, 'Brians Function Finished with Errors!');

            }else{
                console.log('push sent');
                console.log(data);
// Notify Lambda that we are finished

                context.done();
            }
        });
}

function getCredentialsMovement(creator,participant,callback) {

    var params_name = {

        TableName : "users",
        Key : {
            "id" : participant
        },

        ProjectionExpression: 'person_name'

    };
    var params_arn = {

        TableName : "users",
        Key : {
            "id" : creator
        },

        ProjectionExpression: 'arn'

    };

    dynamo.getItem(params_name, function(err, data) {

        var response = {};

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        else {
            console.log("creators name is: "+data.Item.person_name);
            response.name = data.Item.person_name;
            dynamo.getItem(params_arn, function(err, data) {


                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data.Item.arn);

                    response.arn = data.Item.arn;

                    return callback(response);
                }
            });


        }
    });

}
function getCredentialsInvitation(creator,participant,callback) {

    var params_name = {

        TableName : "users",
        Key : {
            "id" : creator
        },

        ProjectionExpression: 'person_name'

    };
    var params_arn = {

        TableName : "users",
        Key : {
            "id" : participant
        },

        ProjectionExpression: 'arn'

    };

    dynamo.getItem(params_name, function(err, data) {

        var response = {};

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        else {
            console.log("creators name is: "+data.Item.person_name);
            response.name = data.Item.person_name;
            dynamo.getItem(params_arn, function(err, data) {


                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return err;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data.Item.arn);

                    response.arn = data.Item.arn;

                    return callback(response);
                }
            });


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where your code is going wrong, but I have some suggestions for debugging it:

1. Turn on CloudWatch Logs for your Lambda function.
2. Make sure each unique path through the code has distinctive log messages, so you can sort out which scenarios are working and which are not.
3. I count 9 calls to `context.done()`, spread across several functions.  You should reduce this to just one or maybe two (success/error). Instead of each function calling `context.done()`, have them use callbacks to return the status back to your top-level handler.
4. You might consider using Promises or a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to make the callback chain easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all of these things already. An engineer of Amazon told me, that it wouldn't matter if i use multiple "context.done()" calls as long as they are logically seperate. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: It would be easier to verify the logic if there is only one statement.  Try running it 100 times with MODIFY and 100 times with INSERT events and calculate the success rate of each path.  That might help you understand what kind of problem it is, and where in the code you should look.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like contex.done() calls are not logically seperate. You have a for loop which has asynchronous calls in it. If there are multiple records in the event there is a chance that they will be processed in the same time and one of them may call context.done() while the other one is still not done.

Assume that you have two MODIFY events coming to this code and for the first db_record_exist function returns r.handle = "true" and the second one returns false. First one will continue to call getCredentials(dynamo.getItem) asynchronously. In the meantime second record will be processed and call context.done() hence ending the lambda function without waiting the response from dynamo